# Does a higher IQ influence the 'high' of weed?

Tags: brain, recreational-drugs, drug-tolerance, iq-intelligence

I'm not sure if this is the best place for the question, but it seemed like the appropriate board to ask on..

So, I'm not asking if Higher IQ= Smoking more weed or anything like that. 
I was just wondering, from my understanding, a higher IQ basically means more connections in the brain. So does a Higher IQ influence how people react to cannabis?

Does that mean you get high faster? Slower? Or does a higher IQ change the 'high' completely? Has any research been done on this?

P.S- I tried to google the topic, but all i found were studies on the correlation of IQ and cannabis use.

Comment: Other than academic interest, can you explain how knowing the answer to this impacts health?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been virtually impossible to do research on cannabis for decades unless that research was intended to find harmful effects. Therefore, no one has investigated this question and any answers would have to be purely speculative.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because after a quick internet search it seems intelligent people are both more likely to try drugs and more likely to become addicted to them...very surprising!

Comment: Someone being "intelligent in the head" (and at IQ test) is not the same as being "intelligent in life."

Comment: @JohnP other than knowing it for the sake of knowing, I don't think it would influence health. Except maybe those with high IQs would be able to look at their friends while smoking and be able to say 'My high so much higher than yours.'. That's pretty much the only benefit.